# VSCode Explorer not showing all files

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I am experiencing that file Explorer in VSCode somehow does not show all files. I have a folder in Unity with some materials, shaders, prefabs, particle effects, etc, and VSCode shows only the particle effect for the same folder (screenshots below).

Folder in Unity:

[image: Folder in Unity:]

Same folder in VSCode's Explorer view, it even shows I have modified something in the folder, which I did, but does not show the changed file:
[image]

I checked for excluded file extensions in VSCode settings, nothing relevant found.

Restarting VSCode, refreshing, reopening the project, do not help.
Any ideas what to check/do/reset next?

Comment: I kinda surprised it shows vfx, its a text editor not a material editor

Comment: Not sure, but you might want to install Unity, C#, C# Dev kit VS Code extensions and see if that helps at all: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioToolsForUnity.vstuc

Comment: @HappyGoLucky, thank you, those are already installed. Except for this everything else works fine, code completion, git, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. Turned out that for some reason a separate .vscode folder exists/appeared on the project level, which contains quite a lot of excludes and those are not visible via File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Files: Exclude.

Hope this helps someone.